# Highcharts Master Detail Chart not rendering 2nd series

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, master-detail

I'm having a problem with setting up a Master Detail chart. Initially both the master and the detail graphs draw both line series and errorbar series. However when selecting a new range on the master only the Line draws within the detail. (Although Master still draws both)

I've added a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/binpower93/za46Y/1/.

I believe the error to be something to do with Highcharts, although it may be caused in the following block of code:

```
selection: function (event) {
                    var extremesObject = event.xAxis[0],
                        min = extremesObject.min,
                        max = extremesObject.max,
                        detailData = [],
                        xAxis = this.xAxis[0];

                    // reverse engineer the last part of the data
                    jQuery.each(this.series, function (i, series) {
                        var data = [];
                        jQuery.each(series.data, function (i, point) {
                            if (point.x > min && point.x < max) {
                                data.push({
                                    x: point.x,
                                    y: point.y
                                });
                            }
                        });
                        detailData.push(data);
                    });

                    // move the plot bands to reflect the new detail span
                    xAxis.removePlotBand('mask-before');
                    xAxis.addPlotBand({
                        id: 'mask-before',
                        from: firstUTC,
                        to: min,
                        color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)'
                    });

                    xAxis.removePlotBand('mask-after');
                    xAxis.addPlotBand({
                        id: 'mask-after',
                        from: max,
                        to: lastUTC,
                        color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)'
                    });

                    jQuery.each(detailChart.series, function (i, series) {
                        detailChart.series[i].setData(detailData[i]);
                    });

                    return false;
                }
            }
        },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that error series requires x/y/high/low value, not only x/y. So when setting you data for second series, you have some NaN's calculated.

Simple way to fix that:

```
                                data.push({
                                    x: point.x,
                                    y: point.y,
                                    high: point.high,
                                    low: point.low
                                });
```

And fixed example: http://jsfiddle.net/za46Y/2/

Small advice: when setting more data/adding more points or series, disable redraw, and call them once, like this:

```
                    jQuery.each(detailChart.series, function (i, series) {
                        series.setData(detailData[i], false);
                    });
                    detailChart.redraw();
```